# How to get the lastet from main branch into feature branch using git?

Tags: git, github

I have a project that is tracked using `Git`. I have `main` branch and then a `feature` branch. The `feature` branch was created from `main`.

My `main` branch is ahead by few commits. How can I get the latest from `main` into `feature` without impacting a pull request back to main?

In other words, after pulling the changing from `main` into `feature`, I want to create a pull request from `feature` back into `main` but don't want the commits that came from `main` to be included into the pull request.

Comment: I'm confused.  You want to get the changes from main into feature without getting the changes from main into feature?  What changes do you want?

Comment: @ChrisDodd sorry, I tried to clarify the question. Please check out the updated question.

Comment: Just rebase your feature branch. That's effectively feature branch basics and should be covered by any tutorial.

Comment: Thank you! `git checkout feature` followed by `git rebase main` did it!